# Why does checking for Nulls in my function's parameter always return None?

Tags: python, function, nonetype

```
from datetime import date 
from datetime import datetime


def get_time_delta(comic1,comic2):
    if comic1 or comic2 is type(None):
        dict1 = comic1["day"],comic1["month"],comic1["year"]
        dict2 = comic1["day"],comic1["month"],comic1["year"]

        date_one = date(comic1["year"],comic1["month"],comic1["day"]) 
        date_two = date(comic2["year"],comic2["month"],comic2["day"]) 
        difference = date_two - date_one 
    else:
        return None
    

comic1, comic2 = get_all_comics(513, 514)  
print(get_time_delta(comic1,comic2))
```

I want the function to return None if parameter1(comic1) or parameter2 (comic2) is None.
However I phrase the sentence, it just always returns None.

The last part, using the function "get_all_comics(513,514)" returns one dict each for each of the two numbers, which I then pass into the get_time_delta function.

I suspect it has something to do with Python not defining the parameters as dictionaries until later in the code, but im not knowledgeable enough in Python to know exactly how it does this.

Comment: `if comic1 or comic2 is type(None):` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Besides wrong use of `or`, also note that `None != type(None)`

Comment: instead of doing `var is type(None)`, try `var is None`, or better yet: `not var`.

Comment: Additionally, your function only returns in the `else` clause. You should probably change that.

Comment: Right.  Use `if not comic1 or not comic2:`, or even `if comic1 is None or comic2 is None:`, if other falsy values are possible.

Comment: And you can delete the `else` clause.  A function without a return statement already returns None.

Comment: Welcome the feedback. Any suggestions to what I can look into?

Comment: @tobias_k Can you explain how this is wrong use of or?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I tried that first. Still returns None

Comment: @TimRoberts I was not aware of that. Thanks for this!